# Where is the yum repository for emacs 23 for CentOS 5.5?

Tags: yum, emacs, rpm

I want to update my emacs on CentOS 5.5 to 23 but I can't find any rpms or yum repos that have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent quite a bit of time trying to build emacs on RHEL5.7, to no avail.
Then, back to the google, and
I found a repo with  emacs23 RPMs for  CentOS/RHEL 5.x.

http://puias.princeton.edu/data/puias/unsupported/5.7/x86_64/

To use it, use the bundled emacs21 to create a text file in `/etc/yum.repos.d/puias-unsupported.repo` .
It should have these contents:

```
[puias-unsupported]
name=PUIAS Unsupported $releasever
baseurl=http://puias.princeton.edu/data/puias/unsupported/5/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=0
```

Then, use it like this:

> sudo yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo=puias-unsupported install emacs23

The RPMs are:

- [emacs23-23.2-5.x86_64.rpm](http://puias.princeton.edu/data/puias/unsupported/5.7/x86_64/emacs23-23.2-5.x86_64.rpm)
- [emacs23-common-23.2-5.x86_64.rpm](http://puias.princeton.edu/data/puias/unsupported/5.7/x86_64/emacs23-common-23.2-5.x86_64.rpm)

If you install it this way, it will be placed into `/usr/emacs23/` . It does not replace the existing emacs21.

There is also a nox version of emacs23 in that repo.  And a bunch of other stuff.

Additionally, to make it work correctly and prevent warnings, I did the following:

> cd /usr/share/emacs/
>
> ln -s /usr/emacs23/share/emacs/23.2
>
> mkdir 23.2/leim
>
> mkdir -p /usr/libexec/emacs/23.2/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu

Answer (score 0):

You could grab the source RPMS from a recent Fedora (or RHEL6) release and then [rebuild them](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/RebuildSRPM) yourself.

Comment: grab them from where? I can't find them anywhere I have been searching Google for the last hour with no luck.

Comment: From a Fedora mirror.  Try searching for `fedora mirrors`.  This will get you to a source for all Fedora packages, such as http://mirror.seas.harvard.edu/fedora/linux/releases/15/Fedora/source/SRPMS/.

Answer (score -2):

The latest version of Emacs on RHEL5 is 21.  Essentially, RHEL/CentOS is aimed at the enterprise server market, which is far more concerned with stability than bleeding edge functionality.

See [this other post](https://serverfault.com/questions/97125/yum-doesnt-update-httpd-past-version-2-2-3-on-centos/97129#97129) for a bit more explanation.

--Christopher Karel

Comment: I know all this, I am looking for a 3rd party repository that has an up to date `emacs` rpm that I can point `yum` at ...

Comment: I'd personally avoid that sort of thing.  Utilizing third party repositories can easily get Yum into dependency loops, making upgrades extremely difficult.  I'd recommend just compiling from source.